# Is it possible to use one Magento Database in two different websites?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using Magento ver. 1.7.0.2. I want to use one database (one backend) for two different websites (one for mobile and other for desktop). How can I do it in Magento?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

You can add muliple website,store inside one database.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [How Multiple Websites & Stores Work](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work)